# How can I check all "a" elements inner text against a set of labels text for matches using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a bunch of "a" elements on my page that hold the day of the month for a calendar. I have hidden labels, each containing a day of the month. I want to use JavaScript to check of there is a match. If there is a match, I want to add HTML nested within the a element.

Here is what I have tried, but it does not work as expected:

```
<span id="eventDayLabel1" class="daysClass">18</span>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6317')" style="color:Black" title="April 18">18</a>

$(function () {
            $('a').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
        });


var elemAs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < elemAs.length; i++) {


       var elemA = elemAs[i];
            var dayLabels = document.getElementsByTagName('daysClass');
            function contains(dayLabels, elemA) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dayLabels.length; i++) {
                    if (dayLabels[i].innerText == elemA.innerText) {
                        // add HTML here
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Why doesn't this piece of code work? I've checked that the labels and a elements are being created there are matches (using inspect element in Chrome).

Comment: it would help if you posted a sample of the a's and labels so we have a working demo that should match/work but isn't.

Comment: I don't see you calling `contains()` anywhere. You defined it but nothing in it will run unless you use it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have added two example elements. There are more just like them that do and do not have matches. When an "a" elements inner text matches one of the labels inner text, I want to add HTML to that specific a element.

Comment: @MichaelCoker How can I get this function to run on when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the `contains()` function and you're using `getElementsByTagName()` to get a `class`.

Just remove the function and the `return false`, and use `getElementsByClassName()` instead.

```js
var elemAs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elemAs.length; i++) {
  var elemA = elemAs[i];
  var dayLabels = document.getElementsByClassName("daysClass");
  //function contains(dayLabels, elemA) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dayLabels.length; i++) {
      if (dayLabels[i].innerText == elemA.innerText) {
        console.log('match');
      }
    }
    //return false;
  //}
}
```

```html
<span id="eventDayLabel1" class="daysClass">18</span>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6317')" style="color:Black" title="April 18">18</a>

<span id="eventDayLabel1" class="daysClass">18</span>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6317')" style="color:Black" title="April 18">17</a>

<span id="eventDayLabel1" class="daysClass">19</span>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6317')" style="color:Black" title="April 18">19</a>
```

Comment: I have this code in "window.onload = function() { in here }". When the page loads it gets stuck in an infinite load and I can't even close my Chrome tab. Any idea why?

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken you have a billion `a` tags or `.daysClass` elements? Not sure without seeing it but that's also beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: There are only two labels, and about 40 a elements on the page.

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken dunno, it could be a ton of things, all I can do is guess and that isn't productive for either of us.

Comment: btw this doesn't have to be in `window.onload`. you can just put it between `script` tags at the end of your html @AndrewMcCracken

Comment: Yeah I moved it out of there and had similar results. I'll keep looking at it but I have no idea why it's not working.